# Keep certain rows as constant in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I have a table, for example:

```
| id | type      |
------------------
| 0  | Complete  |
| 1  | Zone      |
```

Now, I always want my database to be populated with these values, but additionally users should be able to CRUD their own custom types beyond these. For example, a user might decide they want a "Partial Zone" type:

```
| id | type         |
---------------------
| 0  | Complete     |
| 1  | Zone         |
| 2  | Partial Zone |
```

This is all fine. But I don't want anyone to be able to delete/modify the first and second rows.

This seems like it should be so simple, but is there a common strategy for handling this case that ensures that these rows go unaffected? Should I put a lock column on the table and only lock these two values when I initially populate the database on application setup?  Is there something much more obvious and elegant that I am missing?

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you want with sample data? I don't clearly understand your question.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to just add a third column to your table for the user ID/owner of the record.  For the `Complete` and `Zone` records, the owner could be e.g. user 0, which would correspond to an admin.  In your deletion logic, just check the ID column and do not allow admin records to be deleted by anyone from the application.

If this won't work, you could also consider having two tables, one for system records which cannot be deleted, and another one for user created records.  You would have to possibly always take a union of the two tables when you query.